# Is there a flag for mocha.js to prevent it from throwing exception when a test fails?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

An option to prevent it from throwing exception when test fails
is to modify the test script of package.json

in linux :

```
test: mocha dist/test || true
```

in windows :

```
test: mocha dist/test || (exit 0)
```

Since my team works on both the systems, I was wondering if we have any common flag like

```
test : mocha dist/test --dont-throw-exception-when-test-fails
```

Comment: You can wrap it in javascript to make it cross platform. Create a script like `./script/run-test.js` and inside that script do `child_process.exec('mocha dist/test',() => process.exit())` and then call it from your package.json `test: node ./script/run-test.js`

Comment: .. on ALL platforms not throwing an exception from a node.js application is `process.exit()` or `process.exit(0)`